# How to unbrick a non responsive Gio

Tags: unbricking, samsung-galaxy-gio

I downloaded ROM Manager today onto my Samsung Galaxy Gio, and after several attempts to back up my ROM in its current state I tried to reboot my phone into recovery mode through the app. It immediately died, and responds to nothing I do.

I've tried booting it various ways, yet it remains as dead as a battery-less phone (no, charging doesn't do anything, although my battery was low at the time). The phone has been quite stable up till now. I don't have a custom ROM, it is rooted, and everything else is backed up. Is there anything I can do that will work?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't get the device to even turn on, then this will not really help...

From [XDA post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1573628) about unbricking this device:

1. Prepare ODIN with the firmware you want to flash (in my case was Gingerbread 2.3.4) and get it ready to go.
2. Remove battery, wait for a bit. Insert battery again.
3. Flash a recovery with your specific filesystem (EXT4 or RFS)-(If you have EXT4, download ext4 only, don't get ext4+rfs)
4. Enter recovery & Wipe | Format:

   - System
   - Data
   - Cache
   - Dalvik Cache
5. Have ODIN ready. Connect phone to PC.
6. Reboot to Download Mode

   - Hold Volume down + Power + Home button at the same time.
7. At this point Odin should have detected your Galaxy Gio (Yellow rectangle should appear).
8. Insert the Stock Rom or Custom Rom.
9. Click Start button in Odin and wait about 5 min.
10. Reboot and wait

The post has other options like using a tool called "one click unbrick" but I have never tried that tool.

Comment: Wont boot into recovery. I suspect my ROM has been erased, or at least key elements of it. Would a USB jig work, or do I have to take it to a repair shop?

Comment: This doesnt boot it in to recovery, it boots it to download mode.

Comment: Download doesn't work either, tried all various key combinations provided to get it into download mode.